# Divergence of Yamabe soliton

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In the article

*Ma, Li; Cheng, Liang*, [**Properties of complete non-compact Yamabe solitons**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10455-011-9263-3), Ann. Global Anal. Geom. 40, No. 3, 379-387 (2011). [ZBL1225.53038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1225.53038). at page 382, there is a calculation. It says that if take divergence of both sides of the equation
$$\nabla^2f=Rg,$$ where $\nabla^2$ is the Hessian operator, $R$ is the scalar curvature and $f\in C^\infty(M)$, we get
$$\nabla_jR+\frac{1}{n-1}R_{jk}\nabla^kf=0.$$ Please show me the intermediate calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\nabla^k(Rg_{jk})=\nabla_jR$ because $\nabla g=0$.

Second, commuting derivatives using the definition of the Ricci tensor implies that

$$ \nabla^k(f_{jk}) = \nabla^k\nabla_j\nabla_k f= \nabla_j\Delta f + R_{jk}\nabla^k f . $$

Third, the trace of the equation gives $\nabla_j\Delta f = n\nabla_j R$.

Combining these three equations gives the result.

Comment: Thank you very much